# How to hide a tab in java based on the user role

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my application I have three listitems File Upload,View Reports and Change Password. I need to hide View Reports if the login is by normal user and i need to display View Reports if the login is by manager. Below is the code of my tabs

Code in master page-

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu">
             <div class="menu">
                <ul id="drop-nav">
                    <li id="MenuFileUpload" runat="server"><a href="Upload.jsp">File Upload</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="ViewUploadedFiles.jsp">View Uploaded Data</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li id="MenuReports" runat="server"><a href="Reports.jsp" id="Rpf" runat="server">View Reports</a><ul>
                         <li><a href="Reports1.jsp">Report1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="Reports2.jsp">Reports2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="Report3.jsp">Report3</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                         <li id="lichangepwd" runat="server"><a id="A1" href="ChangePassword.jsp" runat="server">Change Password</a></li>
                    <div style="width:auto;float:right;font-weight:bold;padding-right:0cm;">
                        <li id="lilogout"><a href="Logout.jsp"> Logout</a></li></div>
                     <div style="float: left;text-align:right; width: 64%;"> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" BorderColor="White" Text="Label" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label> </div>

                </ul>

             </div>

        </div>
```

code in login page-

```
if(role.equals("Supervisor"))
{
reports.visible=false; 
}
```

I had tried by making reports.visible=false; which we will do in .net but its not working in java

Comment: please note `.net != java`.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically,  you pass some dto that represents logged user into the view. 
Dto (Data transfer object) in most cases contains (login, firstname, lastname and role). Then in the code you do some thing like this:

```
<c:if test="${loggedUserDto.getRole() eq 'ADMIN'}">
   <li id="MenuReports" runat="server"><a href="Reports.jsp" id="Rpf" runat="server">View Reports</a><ul>
                 ....
   </li>
</c:if>
```

If you use spring security :

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    <li ....>
</sec:
```